# How can I call a 4-digit French phone number from the US?

Tags: france

My French bank (Caisse d'Epargne Île de France) wants me to call them at `3241`. I'm currently in the United States. How can I reach such a phone number from the US?

(Assume that the bank doesn't have a 10-digit French phone number, in which case I could just add `+33` and remove the `0`)

Comment: @brhans Thanks, actually this is the phone number for a different bank. I may be able to find an international phone number, but that sometime is not straightforward e.g. https://www.facebook.com/Caisse.Epargne/posts/10153412671670965, so I would prefer to have a way to directly call a 4-digit phone number.

Comment: I think your best bet might be to subscribe to the service of a French VoIP provider so that the call originates into the French phone network as a domestic call. I don't think it is possible to dial those numbers from an international phone.

Comment: To the 4 close voters who didn't leave a comment: [Why would this question on all a 4-digit French phone number from the US be off-topic?](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/q/338/164)

Answer (score 2):

Copying an interesting idea from the comments:

> I think your best bet might be to subscribe to the service of a French VoIP provider so that the call originates into the French phone network as a domestic call. I don't think it is possible to dial those numbers from an international phone. – Dennis ↵ 41 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the carriers your network uses but if they support it just dial +333241
unfortunately if they don't support it, it will dot connect.
I'm afraid there is no work around for this. A French voip termination may work, but again this will depend on their carriers and routing